# Nested While Loop issues

Tags: python, while-loop

So the gist of this is a function that takes two sorted lists. It takes a list of negative numbers (people who owe money) and a list of positive number (people who are owed money). It then pays off the people who are owed money from the negative list.

Example:

```
negatives = [-55.774, -45.884, -40.754, -35.694, -33.734, -29.024, -25.114, -16.144, -14.014, -5.874, -5.554]
positives = [43.936, 42.276, 33.756, 31.116, 30.456, 27.616, 21.526, 18.276, 13.176, 12.376, 11.966, 8.566, 8.486, 4.036]
```

The first step in my process is negatives[0] will pay off the positives[0], 43.936, then it pays off partially positives[1] until itself negatives[0] is 0, it then moves onto negatives[1] and pays off what is owed to positives[1]. I'm just trying to iterate this process. Here's what I have:

```
def pay_balances(x, y):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(x) and j < len(y):
        while abs(x[i]) > abs(y[j]) and abs(round(x[i],4)) != 0:
            print y[j]
            x[i] = x[i] + y[j]
            y[j] = 0
            j += 1
            print i, j
        while abs(x[i]) < abs(y[j]) and abs(round(x[i],4)) != 0:
            print -x[i]
            y[j] = y[j] + x[i]
            x[i] = 0
            i += 1
            print i, j
```

So, if you run...

```
pay_balances(negatives, positives)
```

This will eventually break due to IndexError: list index out of range

The issue is when we are the end of the lists, and my j value = 14 which is when I want everything to stop. It appears to stay in the loop even though I have this line which I thought would kill it:

```
while i < len(x) and j < len(y):
```

What am I doing wrong? As always thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you increment the indices `i` and `j` in the inner loops, you need to put the corresponding condition also in the first inner `while` loop, and add an exit point half-way:

```
while i < len(x) and j < len(y):
    while j < len(y) and abs(x[i]) > abs(y[j]) and abs(round(x[i],4)) != 0:
        print y[j]
        x[i] = x[i] + y[j]
        y[j] = 0
        j += 1
        print i, j
    if j >= len(y):
        break
    while i < len(x) and abs(x[i]) < abs(y[j]) and abs(round(x[i],4)) != 0:
        print -x[i]
        y[j] = y[j] + x[i]
        x[i] = 0
        i += 1
        print i, j
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code generates what you want by using one loop:

```
def pay_balances(x, y):
i = 0
j = 0
while x[-1] != 0 and y[-1] !=0:   
    if abs(x[i]) > abs(y[j]): 
        x[i] = x[i] + y[j]
        y[j] = 0
        j += 1  
    elif abs(x[i]) < abs(y[j]):
        y[j] = y[j] + x[i]
        x[i] = 0
        i += 1         
print x, y
return sum(x) + sum(y)
```